# Detectar Diferencias en 2 Arreglos Vue.js

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

he creado una función en Vue en la que apartir de 2 arreglos, detectar si el primero es diferente al segundo, y concatenar la diferencia.
En caso haya cambiado tengo este formato a la cadena de texto

"**nombreCampo\,\valorOriginal\,\valorModificado**"

Puedes revisar el demo aqui https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/6a0nds79/24/

Si te fijas en la consola correctamente me coloca en la cadena la primer diferencia que es **"codSafi\,\1\,\2\*\"**

Mi problema es que los campos siguientes del arreglo eran Objetos JSON por lo que los nombres se repiten pero no los valores de cada uno y por consecuencia la funcion detecta que eso ha cambiado.

Como modificar la funcion para que no detecte que haya cambiado los valores segun la posicion en el arreglo?

Answer (score 1):

Usa watchers estos se disparan cuando una variable cambian, por ejemplo digamos que tienes una variable question, el watcher que nombres igual que la variable no se lanzara a menos que cambie su valor, este no depende del orden de su contenido sino el resultado final.

La documentacion https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```
data(){
  return {
    question:''
  }
},
watch: {
    question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      console.log('nuevo valor', newQuestion);
      console.log('antiguo valor', oldQuestion);
      // otras acciones a tomar
    }
  },
```